# Erlang- Creating a function which only adds/subtracts positive integers

Tags: programming-languages, concurrency, functional-programming

I want to create a function which allows me to input a list, and then add all of the positive numbers from the list together, leaving any that are negative.

([3,1,-1])
For example only 3 and 1 would be added from this list.

Would I right in thinking the function should be recursive and have a guard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need recursion if you use high-order functions and/or List Comprehensions…

```
sum_positives(List) ->
  lists:sum([X || X <- List, X > 0]).
```

But you might prefer the recursive version of it…

```
sum_positives([]) -> 0;
sum_positives([X|Rest]) when X > 0 -> X + sum_positives(Rest);
sum_positives([_|Rest]) -> sum_positives(Rest).
```